# Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-manifest

Please somebody should help me, i keep getting error with manifest file
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn2jU.png)

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNyDQ.png)

here is the code  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn2jU.png)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="30000" android:versionName="3.0.0" package="com.scriptwriter.webtonative" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNyDQ.png) image 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="org.apache.cordova" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1"> 
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    </manifest>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

based on [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel) you must put `android:hardwareAccelerated` in your Application tag not manifest tag 

Note:
there are many tags in your manifest which are not belongs to manifest file anymore like `versionName` , `versionCode`, `package` 
if it's an un-maintained source code try to update it , if you've de-compiled it try to fix the AndroidStudio migrations .

Comment: Thanks, i will try and see